# Android - Unfortunately, myapp has stopped

Tags: android

I am learning to develop Android applications and have come across a problem with my app. I have created an app that will allow user to type some text and when a button is pressed, a function is called that performs parsing the input string to double and then displays it. I have received no errors, but whenever I run the app on any emulator, it says **"Unfortunately, myapp has stopped"**.

**Here is the LogCat:**

```
04-04 14:34:11.579: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:11.969: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:12.089: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:12.720: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:12.860: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:12.979: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:13.069: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:13.479: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:13.599: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:14.009: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:14.129: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:14.320: D/libEGL(657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-04 14:34:14.390: D/libEGL(657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-04 14:34:14.409: D/(657): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd7820, tid 657
04-04 14:34:14.429: D/libEGL(657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-04 14:34:14.449: D/libEGL(657): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-04 14:34:14.519: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:14.579: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:14.719: W/EGL_emulation(657): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-04 14:34:14.769: D/OpenGLRenderer(657): Enabling debug mode 0
04-04 14:34:15.049: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:15.173: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:15.579: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:15.790: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:16.030: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:16.109: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:16.549: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:16.739: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:17.029: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:17.220: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:27.099: D/AndroidRuntime(657): Shutting down VM
04-04 14:34:27.099: W/dalvikvm(657): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  ... 11 more
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText@40f7be40"
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.example.coinage.MainActivity.convert(MainActivity.java:25)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  ... 14 more
04-04 14:34:28.069: I/dalvikvm(657): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-04 14:34:28.179: I/dalvikvm(657): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 14:34:29.729: I/Process(657): Sending signal. PID: 657 SIG: 9
```

**Method that performs Computation**

```
public void convert(View view){
    int countOf2Po = 0, countOf1Po = 0, countOf50p = 0, countOf20p = 0, countOf2p = 0, countOf1p = 0;
    EditText amt = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.amount);
    TextView penny = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.penny);
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString()) * 100;
    while(amount >= 200){
        amount = amount - 200;
        countOf2Po++;
    }
    while(amount >= 100){
        amount = amount - 100;
        countOf1Po++;
    }
    while(amount >= 50){
        amount = amount - 50;
        countOf50p++;
    }
    while(amount >= 20){
            amount = amount - 20;
            countOf20p++;
    }
    while(amount >= 2){
        amount = amount - 2;
        countOf2p++;
    }
    if(amount % 2 != 0){
        countOf1p++;
    }
    penny.setText("Converting " + penny + " into coins.");
    penny.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText@40f7be40"` Invalid double. Post the relevant code

Comment: `java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
04-04 14:34:27.219: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.example.coinage.MainActivity.convert(MainActivity.java:25)`  You need to show your code.  Line 25 is the problem.

Comment: So which one is line 25?  My guess is `double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString()) * 100;` but why not tell us instead of having to guess?

Comment: yeah that is the line. But what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Without knowing what the value in `amt` is, who knows?  We guess again.  My guess is that it's empty but whatever, it contains a value which is not a valid double.  You really should read the documentation and learn how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast the `toString()` value of the `EditText` to a double, which is not the text entered into the `EditText` like you expected, but the name the name of the class concatenated with the instance's hash code:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

What you want to do, is to retrieve the entered text using `getText()`, and convert that to a `String`:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.getText().toString()) * 100;
```

Note that this may lead to a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not a proper double.